# SQL Server : query to show only a value on last occurrence

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to list a value only on a last occurrence of a jobnumber?

Our database holds orders which have jobs that have numbers. `OrderNo-0011` for example. The `0011` is the job indication.

Per job more tasks can be preformed, but only one time per job I want to list the used materials, now when I join in the table that holds the materials, it lists on all lines with the job number the amount used. It should be that only the last or first is filled and the rest may be NULL or empty.

Example what now happens:

```
JobNo         Task        Material   Starttime   Endtime    Operator
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
122070-0011   Set-Up      4          DateTime    Datetime   Willy Wonka
122070-0011   Production  4          DateTime    Datetime   Willy Wonka
122070-0011   Waste       4          DateTime    Datetime   Willy Wonka
122070-0011   Cleanup     4          DateTime    Datetime   Willy Wonka
```

It should only show the amount on the last or first record:

```
JobNo         Task        Material   Starttime   Endtime    Operator
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
122070-0011   Set-Up      NULL       DateTime    Datetime   Willy Wonka
122070-0011   Production  NULL       DateTime    Datetime   Willy Wonka
122070-0011   Waste       NULL       DateTime    Datetime   Willy Wonka
122070-0011   Cleanup     4          DateTime    Datetime   Willy Wonka
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you could use a CASE statement and the ROW_NUMBER function (assuming you are using SQL Server 2008 or later).

Eg:

```
SELECT
   JobNo, Task, 
   CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY JobNo ORDER BY StartTime DESC) = 1
        THEN Material
        ELSE NULL END AS Material,
   Starttime,
   Endtime,
   Operator
FROM
   MyTable
ORDER BY JobNo, Starttime
```

(swapping the order by in the ROW_NUMBER OVER clause to ASC would get it on the first item)

I have to say, I can't quite see the value of doing this, but hey, that wasn't the question :)

Comment: Thanks! This does the trick for me. It's going to be used to have it as value in a report, where the material used is needed to calculate various things.